# Paginar y ordenar lista completa en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, angular-directivas

Tengo una lista de registros que muestro con `ng-repeat` que estoy ordenando por *phone* y la estoy paginando.

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos | orderBy:'phone':true">{{todo.phone}}</li>
```

Necesito ordenar y paginar la lista, pero al adicionar el `orderBy:'phone':true` solo se ordena los registros de cada pagina en vez de ordenar la lista completa, tengo claro que es por la lógica del paginador, pero no encuentro una lógica que me permita paginar y ordenar toda la lista completa.
 aqui el ejemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module('todos',['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('TodoController', function($scope) {
      $scope.filteredTodos = []
  ,$scope.currentPage = 1
  ,$scope.numPerPage = 5
  ,$scope.maxSize = 5;
  
  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.todos = [];
    for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
    $scope.todos=[
    
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'eeeeee XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'ffffff XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'}
    ];
  };
  $scope.makeTodos(); 
  
  $scope.numPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.todos.length / $scope.numPerPage);
  };
  
  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    
    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
  });
   
   
});
```

```html
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="todos" ng-controller="TodoController">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <h4>{{todos.length}} remain</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos | orderBy:'phone':true">{{todo.phone}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numPages()" 
      data-current-page="currentPage" data-max-size="maxSize"  
      data-boundary-links="true"></div>
  </body>
```

[Aqui](https://github.com/x-rw/gossipjs) el codigo de ejemplo similar del paginador que tengo.

Mi lista tiene varias columnas y se obtiene consumiendo un servicio el cual no puedo modificar, lo que tengo en mente es que se debe modificar la lógica de paginar la lista y hay mismo aplicar el orden.

Comment: lo que quieres decir que tienes un arreglo de n elementos y al realizar el order por el paginado solo ordena lo que se visualiza en el html?

Comment: Si, solo se ordena los 10 primeros registros en vez de ordenar todos los registros completamente.

Comment: y donde haces el paginado?, lo haces antes de ordenar?

Comment: El paginado lo hago en el controllador, el cual es similar al la lógica que esta en [este ejemplo](http://embed.plnkr.co/D8ikkz/) en las ultimas lineas del archivo **scripts.js**.

Comment: por favor revisa el enlace

Comment: Perdona, acabaron de tumbar el link, cargue el código [aquí en github](https://github.com/kradwarrior/temporal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error es que estas haciendo el corte del array y luego paginarlo la solucion es ordenarlo primero y luego cortar el array.debes agregar la linea luego de cargar el `Array`

```
$scope.todos=  $filter('orderBy')($scope.todos, 'phone', false);
```

si quieres ordenarlo descentendte solo cambia el true por el false

```
 $scope.todos=  $filter('orderBy')($scope.todos, 'phone', true);
```

y quitar el filtro ya que lo estar ordenando previamente

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos">
```

el ejemplo completo a continuacion:

```js
var app = angular.module('todos',['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('TodoController', function($scope,$filter) {
      $scope.filteredTodos = []
 ,$scope.currentPage = 1
  ,$scope.numPerPage = 5
  ,$scope.maxSize = 5;
  
  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.todos = [];
    for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
    $scope.temp=[
    
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'eeeeee XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'ffffff XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'},
       {'phone': 'Nexus S'},
       {'phone': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'},
       {'phone': 'AMOTOROLA XOOM™'}
    ];
$scope.todos=  $filter('orderBy')($scope.temp, 'phone', false);
  };
  $scope.makeTodos(); 
  
  $scope.numPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.todos.length / $scope.numPerPage);
  };
  
  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    
    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
  });
   
   
});
```

```html
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="todos" ng-controller="TodoController">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <h4>{{todos.length}} remain</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos ">{{todo.phone}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numPages()" 
      data-current-page="currentPage" data-max-size="maxSize"  
      data-boundary-links="true"></div>
  </body>
```

> En conclusion Debes primero ORDENAR y luego PAGINAR

Comment: Gracias JackNavaRow :D